# Vue js v-link same route does not update content

Tags: vue.js

If I am at the route:

```
person/:slug
```

And I click a link:

```
<div v-for="person in persons" v-link="{ name: 'person', params: { slug: person.slug }}">
```

The URL will change the parameter but the actual content/component does not update. If I hit refresh it will since the URL is updated. I have tried the canReuse property without any luck.

Routes:

```
router.map({
    '/': {
        name: 'search',
        component: Search
    },
    '/person/:slug': {
        name: 'person',
        component: Person
    }
})
```

Component:

```
<template>
    {{ person.slug }}
</template>


<script>
    import PersonRepository from '../person-repository.vue'

    export default {
        data () {
            return { person: null }
        },
        asyncData (resolve, reject) {
            return PersonRepository.get(this, this.$route.params.slug).then((person) => {
                return { person: person }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this using router hooks instead of async data?  The recommended way is router hooks now.

You specifically need the data hook:  http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/pipeline/data.html

> Called on an incoming component during the activation phase, after the activate hook has been resolved. **It is also called when the route has changed and the current component is reused.** Use this hook to load and set data on the current component.

```
export default {
    data () {
        return { person: null }
    },
    route:{ 
        data: function (transition) {
            return PersonRepository.get(this, this.$route.params.slug).then((person) => {
                return { person: person }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

By returning a promise, your component will reload when the promise is resolved.  Additionally you have access to a property `$loadingRouteData` which you can use to display a loading spinner or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## Watch the route for change and fetch your data

For version 3+ of vue-router you can use watchers and watch the `$route` then update your data accordingly:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return { person: null }
    },

    watch: {
       // call the method if the route changes
       '$route': {
         handler: 'asyncData',
         immediate: true // runs immediately with mount() instead of calling method on mount hook
       }
    },

    methods: {
       asyncData () {
           // ... your person fetching code
       }
    }
}
```

You can fetch after the route changes or before. See [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html) on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```